# How to create a custom shape button background?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-button

I am trying to make a custom background for my button(simple) but it is not displaying properly. it only displays the following output.

[image]

Create Room(btn_create_room_bg) :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="360dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="360dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Join Room(btn_join_room_bg):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="360dp"
                android:topRightRadius="360dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Button code:
Here are my two-button codes in a linear layout.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="300dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_create_room_bg"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
            android:text="@string/landing_btn_create_room"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_join_room_bg"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
            android:text="@string/landing_btn_join_room"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I need an output like this.

[image]

Comment: please specify on what type of button you are working (simple button or other)?

Comment: I'm working on a simple button. Added the code to be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a custom **`CornerTreatment`** with the `MaterialButton`.

You can extend the default [`CutCornerTreatment`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.2.0-beta01/lib/java/com/google/android/material/shape/CutCornerTreatment.java):

```
public class FullCutCornerTreatment extends CutCornerTreatment {

    protected static final float ANGLE_LEFT = 180;

    public FullCutCornerTreatment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void getCornerPath(
            @NonNull ShapePath shapePath, float angle, float interpolation, float radius) {
        shapePath.reset(0, 2*radius * interpolation, ANGLE_LEFT, 180 - angle);
        shapePath.lineTo(
                (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * radius * interpolation),
                (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90 - angle)) * radius * interpolation));
    }
}
```

Then just apply the `CornerTreatment` to the `Button`:

```
MaterialButton materialButton = findViewById(R.id....);
FullCutCornerTreatment customCutCornerTreatment = new FullCutCornerTreatment();

materialButton.setShapeAppearanceModel(materialButton.getShapeAppearanceModel().toBuilder()
        //Standard rounded corner with corner radius=50%
        .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,new RelativeCornerSize(0.5f))
        .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,new RelativeCornerSize(0.5f))
        //Square angle
        .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,0)
        //Full cut corner
        .setBottomRightCorner(customCutCornerTreatment)
             .setBottomRightCornerSize(new RelativeCornerSize(0.5f))
        .build());
```

[image]

Just a note about `new RelativeCornerSize(0.5f)`: It changed in `1.2.0-beta01`. Before it was `new RelativeCornerSize(50))`.